# Artinian finite dimensional algebra properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I am confused  in the deduction from the text, "Algebraic Number Theory", by Taylor. On p51, the author claimed 1,2, below as a direct consequence of 0.

> **0.** Let $A$ denote a finite dimensional commutative $F$-algebra. Then $Rad(A)=0$ iff   $A \cong \prod A_i$ with each $A_i$ a field.
>
> **1.** If $A$ is a finite dimensional commutative $F$- algebra, then it has finitely many maximal ideals. 
>   **2.** If $A$ is also an integral domain, then it is a field.

I could prove 1,2 individually from artinian proeprties. But I am quite confused why $0 \Rightarrow 1,2$.

Comment: For the first one, the quotient by the radical is semisimple, i.e. a product of simple rings. Since is is also commutative, those will be fields.

Comment: Sorry, I edited so my question is clearer. I wanted to know why 0 => 1,2. I already know how to prove 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the comments,take $B=A/Rad(A)$ and use $0$. This tells you that  $B$ as a finitely generated algebra is s field product,then has only finitely many  maximal ideals. Also maximal ideals of $B$ are exactly the ones of $A$. If $A$ is a domain, $Rad(A)=0$ and then use $0$ again and that a product of rings is not likely to be a domain.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I see the problem was I didn't know what the ideals of a product of rings are.

Comment: Uhm we have to be clear:what's ur definiton of radical of a ring?

Comment: The set of nilpotent elements. Its the nil radical according to wikipedia.

Comment: Ok,you can try to show that it is the intersection of all prime ideals.

Comment: I have figured out the problem, thanks a lot.